# How Can I Make These Nice Checkboxes AJAX Post Like This Other Button?

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I have pretty (but non-functional) checkboxes beside a normal Submit button (that works fine on my server).

How can I make the pretty checkbox initiate an AJAX Post?

I've tried every combination I could think of.

```
<form  id="form" action='result.php' method='post'>

<ul class="listview checkbox-strip">
    <li><!-- li helps with formatting -->

        <label class="checkbox">
            <input name="quantity" value="one" type="checkbox">
            <input name="prod_id" value="62" type="hidden">
            <span class="label-text">Orange</span>
        </label>
    <BR>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input name="quantity" value="5" type="checkbox">
            <input name="prod_id" value="62" type="hidden">
            <span class="label-text">Yellow</span>
        </label>


        <label class="checkbox">
        <input name="quantity" value="one" type="checkbox"></label>
        <input type=hidden name="prod_id" value=10>
        <input type="button" value="This Button Works on my server" id="submit">
</li>
</form>
<div id = "container"></div>
```

No error yet, just not able to trigger the Post with either of the two checkboxes.

Here's a fiddle of it where everything works but the post.  The post works on my server.

https://jsfiddle.net/FredSmith/wktvhy60/21/

Thanks for your help

SOLVED

Put this $(":checkbox") in place of $("#submit")

Comment: I'm a bit confused on the intended functionality. Do you want the post to occur immediately on click of either checkbox?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Immediately upon clicking a checkbox.  Clicking once would put a record in, and the next click would remove the record.  Thanks!

Comment: `$(":checkbox").click(function() ...)` to execute something when the user checks the box.

Comment: Take a look at the JavaScript console in jsfiddle: **Uncaught Error: Shoestring does not support the click method. Try using trigger( 'click' ) instead.**

Comment: So you're actually using Shoestring, not jQuery. Maybe you should use the real thing.

Comment: @Barmar Thank You!  The $(":checkbox") is the fix.  I should know that by now.  Thanks again.